# Cannot add edit themes and add plugins after multisite update

Tags: plugins, multisite, themes, updates

After updating a multisite installation to WP 3.8, when in the My Sites Dashboard, hovering over "Themes" or "Plugins", no submenu pops out.
There are however submenus popping out of "Sites", "Users", and "Settings".

I found advice elsewhere to disable plugins one by one, and make sure a standard theme is being used. However, with a multisite installation I suppose there is no way to make sure a standard theme is being used (unless all sites are changed to that theme).

Any ideas how to understand and fix this situation?
Is there anywhere to locate an error message?

I should mention that one of the sites is using a private plugin that I wrote, but it does not seem to have any problems as far as I can tell.

Comment: If you can install this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

It has a debug bar which may be of help identifying the error

Comment: Thanks @CraigPearson I installed that, but it is not obvious what to do next... it does not seem to be showing any major errors.

Comment: Have you clicked the dropdown and inspected the items under "PHP Errors" or "PHP Warnings"? This is a wildshot but generally this happens when the correct version of jQuery is not loading for the dashboard. While logged in you could check this in your browser. I.e. in Chrome right click and choose inspect element - go to the console tab and see if there are any undefined errors thrown this will confirm the issue. Or, in the Elements tab search for jQuery and ensure the correct version is loaded. WP 3.9 should have jQuery V1.11.0. WP 3.8 should have jQuery 1.10.2

Comment: @CraigPearson the Html shows that there is not supposed to be any submenu under Plugins and Themes and there is no js error reported, but I still kind of think you are onto something. ..

Comment: We can confirm JS is the error by placing: `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);` in your `wp-config` file in the root of your install and see if your issue "goes away". I'm going to take a really wild guess here and presume you have a caching plugin enabled or some kind of issue with loading JS from a CDN. If you do have a caching plugin like W3 Total Cache then network disable that to test the results

Comment: @CraigPearson I checked and actually I am loading an old version of jQuery because I foolishly included that in my child theme. Some other reason is preventing me from fixing that right now, but I think you hit the nail on the head! If you post the jQuery issue as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wildshot but generally this happens when the correct version of jQuery is not loading for the dashboard.

While logged in you could check this in your browser. I.e. in Chrome right click and choose inspect element - go to the console tab and see if there are any undefined errors thrown this will confirm the issue.

Or, in the Elements tab search for jQuery and ensure the correct version is loaded.

WP 3.9 should have jQuery V1.11.0
WP 3.8 should have jQuery V1.10.2

We can further help confirm JS is the error by placing: `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);` in your `wp-config` file in the root of your install and see if your issue "goes away".

Comment: Actually it's still not working, but the jQuery thing may turn out to be the solution yet...